# Self-referenced type restriction on inferred type argument in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-definitions

I want to have an object builder that should infer types similar to how [zod.js](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) does.

It should receive fallbacks as an argument and return an object to work with.
Fallback could be a value or a function that returns a value. That function should also be able to use other fields as an argument.

In a simple case it should be something like this:

```
type TypeOf<T> =
    T extends (...args: any) => any ? TypeOf<ReturnType<T>> | null : 
    T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: TypeOf<T[K]> } : T;

type Without<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

type Fields<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: string | (<A extends Without<T, K>>(arg: A) => string);
};

declare function build<T>(fallbacks: Fields<T>) : TypeOf<T>;

// `obj` should have inferred type `{ simple: string, fallback: string }`
const obj = build({
    simple: "test",
    fallback: (obj) => `hello, ${obj.simple}`, //  <--  obj has unknown type
});

console.log(obj); // { simple: "test", fallback: "hello, test" }

obj.simple = "world";
console.log(obj); // { simple: "world", fallback: "hello, world" }

obj.fallback = "custom"; 
console.log(obj); // { simple: "world", fallback: "custom" }

obj.fallback = null; 
console.log(obj); // { simple: "world", fallback: "hello, string" }
```

It is working if I strictly define my type:

```
type MyType = {
    simple: string
    fallback: string | null
}

const obj = build<MyType>({ ... });
```

Or if I remove constrictions on the fallback function argument:

```
type Fields<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: string | ((arg: any) => string);
};
```

So, either type inference not working or the fallback function argument isn't well typed.

As I understand, the main issue is the type argument could be in "inference" mode that resolves types from what it has or in "restriction" mode that checks values by passed types.

Is there a way to have a partial self-referenced type restriction on inferred type argument?

Comment: I think fundamentally this sort of recursive inference is not possible in general, despite some [improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods) for some common cases.  But your question maybe could be cleaned up a bit before it's in a good state to answer.  First, your `Without` is identical to the built-in [`Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys), so you should use that instead.  Second, I don't think ...

Comment: ... you want the callback to be generic in `<A extends Omit<T, K>>(arg: A) => string`; it doesn't seem to be an improvement over just `(arg: Omit<T, K>) => string`.  Third, that callback and the value type are exclusively `string`?  Shouldn't it be a function of `T`?  Fourth, why are you applying `TypeOf<T>`?  It looks like it should be `TypeOf<Fields<T>>` which should then be equivalent to just `T`... you want `build()` to return a `T`, right?  Or maybe a `{[K in keyof T]: T[K] | null}`.

Comment: Fifth, it would be nice to see an implementation of build() that works as advertised; it's possible you could use something like partial application to get behavior you want (e.g., maybe `builder.add({simple: "test"}).addCb({fallback: (obj) => \`hello, ${obj.simple}\`).build()`)... but without an implementation it's hard to know

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

My best guess for now is `declare function build<T>(fn: () => { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | ((arg: Omit<T, K>) => T[K]) }) : T;`

It is working good until fallback argument is not used. Otherwise T comes `unkown` :(

Implementation example: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-curran-gjteyb?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Please [edit] the question to put the new version in the question *as plaintext* so we can focus on the inference.  Perhaps the code from [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wk03pw) would be best?

Comment: And then [this version](https://tsplay.dev/W4PJ4W) would be my suggested approach; instead of trying to get the compiler to do weird partial recursive inference, use a builder approach to explicitly break the inference info steps.  At each point along the way, you can only access properties that have already been defined in prior steps (this is strictly better than `Omit<T, K>`, since something like `{foo: v => v.bar, bar: v => v.foo}` is clearly invalid but is allowed by `Omit<T, K>`).  If that works for your needs I could write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing?